# Logback logging format

Tags: slf4j, logback

In logback, {} is not getting replaced by the data ("param" in the below example).
This happens in SLF4J. Can't this format be used in logback? Do I need to append the information using "+"?

LOGGER.info( "Parameter : {}", param );

Comment: how did you instantiate your LOGGER?

Comment: Yes. 
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( <classname>.class );

Logs are printed..but along with  {}.

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue.
I was using the log as below with multiple ",". So the log after 2nd "," was not getting logged.

LOGGER.debug( "Param 1 -> {}", param1 , "Param 2 {}” , param2 ," Params 3 {} "+ param3);

Corrected it :
LOGGER.debug( "Param 1 -> {}, Param 2 -> {}, Param 3 -> {}", param1 , param2, param3);

Sorry to bother. Thanks for all help.